# How to know the storage type that a GCE instance is using in console

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm in the GCE (Google Compute Engine) consoles for all my VMs. I'd like to check what storage option each of them is using. By *storage option* I mean `pd-standard`, `pd-balanced`, `pd-extreme` or `pd-ssd`. The reference is [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks).

Answer (score 1):

@Isalkari, I agree with your answer. To check the Storage type of your GCE instance :

1. In the Cloud Console, go to the Compute Engine.
2. Go to the Storage Option.
3. Click on Disks

[image]

If you create a disk in the Cloud Console, the default disk type is `pd-balanced`. If you create a disk using the gcloud tool or the Compute Engine API, the default disk type is `pd-standard`.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer: Just enter the google cloud console and check `Storage/Disks` on the left.

Comment: Is this an answer or a comment for your question? If an answer, expand the answer with more details. If a comment, then delete this answer and repost as a comment to your question.

Comment: @JohnHanley was trying to answer. Added more details to it. Thanks!